# How do you properly pass a variable of a SwiftUI class of into the ContentView?

Tags: swiftui, mapbox

I'm using the Mapbox SDK...in my MapViewCoordinator class (this class adopts the protocols NSObject,  the MGLMapViewDelegate and I THINK, but am not sure about, the ObservableObject protocol), I have a @State variable called annotationSelected. The value of this variable is changed when map annotations are selected. I'm trying to access this annotationSelected variable from ContentView but I'm not sure how to do it. Here is my MapViewCoordinator code:

```
class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, Observable Object, MGLMapViewDelegate {
@State var annotationSelected = false
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) ->
    Bool {
    return true
}
//Other functions that change the value of annotationSelected
}
```

I'm confused because I don't think I can pass in an INSTANCE of this class into content view (like you normally would with an observable object)...let me know if you guys need any other parts of my code in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `@State` is designed to be in View, and `ObservableObject` has `@Published` for dynamic update, so use as below

```
class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, ObservableObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
   @Published var annotationSelected = false
```